# Failing to clear previously displayed labels on radiobutton click in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am working on dynamic generation of labels based on radiobutton click. Well I have been succesful in doing it but everytime I click a button, it generates labels but doesnt clear the previous state. Here is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">                     

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <RadioButton Content="{Binding RadioBase}" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding BaseCheck}" GroupName="SlotGroup" />                            
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>           
    </Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">            

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsControl Visibility="{Binding IsRegisterItemsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConv}}" ItemsSource="{Binding RegisterLabels}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,20,0,0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>            
    </Grid>
```

**FPGARadioWidgetViewModel Class:** DataContext of this class is set here

```
public ObservableCollection<FPGAViewModel> Children { get; set; }

    public FPGARadioWidgetViewModel()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<FPGAViewModel>();
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x0", ID = 0 });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x40", ID = 1 });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0x80", ID = 2 });
        Children.Add(new FPGAViewModel() { RadioBase = "Base 0xc0", ID = 3 });            
    }
```

**FPGAViewModel Class:**

```
private bool sBaseCheck;
    public bool BaseCheck
    {
        get { return this.sBaseCheck; }
        set
        {
            this.sBaseCheck = value;
            Generatelabels(this, ID);
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BaseCheck");
        }
    }

    private static void Generatelabels(FPGAViewModel currentItem, int index)
    {
        int m_baseRegister = 0;

        if (index == 0)
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < 0x40 / 8; i++)
            {
                int reg = (i * 8) + m_baseRegister;
                currentItem.RegisterLabels[i] = "Reg 0x" + reg.ToString("X");
                currentItem.IsRegisterItemsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        else if (index == 1)
        {
            m_baseRegister = 0x40 * index;
            for (int i = 0; i < 0x40 / 8; i++)
            {
                int reg = (i * 8) + m_baseRegister;
                currentItem.RegisterLabels[i] = "Reg 0x" + reg.ToString("X");
                currentItem.IsRegisterItemsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        // Similarly for Index 2 and Index = 3
    }

    private string[] registerLabels = new string[8];
    public string[] RegisterLabels { get { return registerLabels; } }

    private bool isRegisterItemsVisible = false;
    public bool IsRegisterItemsVisible
    {
        get { return isRegisterItemsVisible; }
        set
        {
            isRegisterItemsVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsRegisterItemsVisible");
            OnPropertyChanged("RegisterLabels");
        }
    }
```

On radiobutton click, it displays 8 labels. When i click second radiobutton, it displays another 8 and doesn't clear the previous 8. Basically at one time only 8 labels of selected radiobutton must be displayed. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but possibly WPF is getting confused because you are firing `PropertyChanged` for `RegisterLabels`, when the array object itself hasn't changed, only the content has.

Usually if you have a collection that has changing content in WPF, you use an `ObservableCollection` instead, which supports `INofityCollectionChanged` to tell WPF when items it contains have changed (Like you do for `Children`)

Either that, or create a new array each time in `GenerateLabels` and then assign it to your `RegisterLabels` property at the end.

ps. Why is your `GenerateLabels()` method static? It would be much cleaner if it were just a normal instance method, then you wouldn't have to pass in `currentItem` and `index`.

**EDIT**: Example of second method (replacing array)

```
public string[] RegisterLabels { get; private set; }

private void Generatelabels()
{
    string[] labels = new string[8];
    int baseRegister = 0x40 * ID;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int reg = (i * 8) + baseRegister;
        labels[i] = "Reg 0x" + reg.ToString("X");
    }

    RegisterLabels = labels;
    OnPropertyChanged("RegisterLabels");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could be elaborate with a sample code? I think it will really be helpful :)

Comment: @SteveWilson this is the third time I see you asking for sample code to do this. I already explained to you the mindset you needed to create the hiearchical relationship you needed between your objects to accomplish this. Please don't be lazy and stop asking other people you do your job. =)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer:Well this surely does display labels as expected :) but looks like OnPropertyChanged doesnt get triggered when i click other 3 radiobuttons. It displays labels for only 1 st button.